# How to search for an item in an arraylist?

Tags: java

I am creating a gui that can add,remove and search for a name that a user inputs. I would like to know the code that lets me search for items in the arraylist. Thank you

Comment: Please pick up a book on Java or read the docs/tutorial.

Comment: We don't write code for you here, and you read that in the welcome page for this site (or should have as you have the metal that says you did).

Comment: Have you tried implementing anything? have you tried searching StackOverflow?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Object)
```

method it will return the index position of first occurrence of the element in the list.

Or

```
java.util.ArrayList.Contains(Object o)
```

The above method will return true if the specified element available in the list.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using predicate to search in a stream representing you list, here is a simple example :

```
List<String> listOfUsersName = Arrays.asList("toto", "tata", "joe", "marou", "joana", "johny", "");

String userInputSearch = "jo";

List<String> result =listOfUsersName.stream()
                                    .filter(user -> user.contains(userInputSearch))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Please note that this is for Java 8 only.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question did not provide sufficient information, I'll make some things up:

```
//This is your array list that you want to search in:
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); // Assume this is full of stuff

//This is the user input
private String userInput;

//This method will be called when the search button is clicked
public void onSearchClick() {

}
```

This is how you are going to implement the search algorithm:

> For each item in the array list, if it contains the search string, add it to the search results.

That makes a lot of sense, doesn't it?

In code, you would write this:

```
private ArrayList<String> searchInList(ArrayList<String> list, String searchString) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (item in list) {
        if (item.contains(searchString)) {
            results.add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

And then in the `onSearchClick` method, you call the search method and do something with the results.

```
public void onSearchClick() {
    ArrayList<String> searchResults = searchInList(names, userInput);
    // display the results or whatever
}
```

If you want a case-insensitive search, you can change the if statement in the search method to this:

```
if (item.toLowercase().contains(searchString.toLowercase()))
```